# How do you make json-rpc calls in PHP dynamic?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the easybitcoin.php script [here](https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP):

(It makes json-rpc calls to bitcoind)

I've made a seperate php file, that retrieves the data from the easybitcoin.php file such as balance, accounts..etc. And spits it out on a page.

When making a json-RPC call, such as:

```
retrieve_once('easybitcoin.php');
print_r($<username>->getbalance($_SESSION['username']) );
```

You need to refresh the page to get your updated balance, how would you make it dynamic where the user does not have to refresh the page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX GET request:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;
client.open("GET", "yourPhpFile.php");
client.send();
```

Create the handler:

```
function processData(data) {
  // taking care of data
}

function handler() {
  if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
    if(this.status == 200 &&
       this.responseXML != null) {
      // success!
      processData(this.responseXML);
      return;
    }
    // something went wrong
    processData(null);
  }
}
```

In the `processData` function do whatever you want with the data you receive from the server.
In the `yourPhpFile.php` you should include the easybitcoin.php file and make the necessary calls.

Now you can encapsulate your AJAX request in `setInterval()`, this way it will periodically get updates.